# Wireless driver not working

Tags: wireless, drivers, realtek

I have a problem using wireless in my laptop. I think the driver is not installed and all I am getting to that is a Realtek driver.

Is there any methods to install/setup the required driver ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try installing this driver over at Github:  https://github.com/FreedomBen/rtl8188ce-linux-driver

It has not been tested with your card but it fixes a lot of the issues with other RealTek cards (especially 8188CE).

The driver purports to support the 8723E.  I haven't found anything that says it is incompatible with the 8723AE but you should still proceed with caution.  However, if you can't get the card to work at all then definitely give this a try.

Answer (score 0):

You might be correct that your drivers are not installed. However, also check if your WIFI card is on (Most laptops have a hotkey to turn WIFI on or off).

Then try to issue the following command the know which WIFI card you are using.

`sudo lshw -C network`

Upon knowing the model and make of your wifi card, just look for its driver and install.

Comment: I had came up with the following `RTL8723AE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter`. What should I do next ?